# Compare very large tables in java

Tags: java, compare, resultset

I am not able to find any satisfying solution so asking here.
I need to compare data of two large tables(~50M)  with the same schema definition in JAVA.
I can not use order by clause while getting the resultset object and records might be not in order in both of the tables.
Can anyone help me what can be the right way to do it?

Comment: Depending on the nature of your data and your comparison, you may be able to do all of the processing in your query instead of in Java. Alternatively, if your issue is memory, this would be a reasonable justification for increasing the max heap size.

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the data of the first DB table into a text file, and create a while loop on the resultSet for the 2nd table. As you iterate through the ResultSet do a search/verify against the text file. This solution works if memory is of concern to you.

If not, then just use a HashMap to hold the data for the first table and do the while loop and look up the records of the 2nd table from the HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

This really depends on what you mean by 'compare'?  Are you trying to see if they both contain the exact same data?  Find rows in one not in the other? Find rows with the same primary keys that have differing values?

Also, why do you have to do this in Java?  Regardless of what exactly you are trying to do, it's probably easier to do with SQL.

In Java, you'll want to create an class that represents the primary key for the tables, and a second classthat represents the rest of the data, which also includes the primary key class. If you only have a single column as the primary key, then this is easier.

We'll call P the primary key class, and D the rest.

Map map = new HashMap();
Select all of the rows from the first table, and insert them into the hash map.
Query all of the rows in the second table. 
For each row, create a P object.
Use that to see what data was in the first table with the same Key.
Now you know if both tables contained the same row, and you can compare the non-key values from both both.

Like I said, this is much much easier to do in straight SQL.
You basically do a full outer join between the two tables.  How exactly that join looks depends on exactly what you are trying to do.